# printing threads in strict order

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to print threads in specific order. So I have a main method which starts 10 threads. I need to print in the following order:

main thread started

thread 0 started
thread 1 started
.
.
thread 9 started

thread 0 finished
thread 1 finished
.
.
.
thread 9 finished

main thread finished

I have tried with join() method where main thread joins after each thread has started and finished.

This only solves half the problem. I also need to print start of each thread and then finished of each new thread.

Any suggestions.

Comment: You might need to think differently. Instead of printing out the results from each Thread immediately after they finish, consider storing up the results until you have them all, then sorting them, then printing them out.

Comment: This seems to be a homework. Please post some code showing what you have tried with `join`. Do you think `join` is the right approach? Why?

Comment: @Paul I don't think that is the idea behind this homework :)

Comment: Look at the CountdownLatch class, each thread can do an action, the countdown on a latch for the next thread

Comment: in case of join() method, this would just be the case of sequential execution. I feel that join() isn't a good idea either. However, without join() or without keeping a count variable and then checking whether the thread name is equal to the count variable and then waiting on a Lock is also not a good idea as this would lead to cumbersome code, I cant think of any other approach. CountdownLatch could be way to go, however, isn't is possible to achieve this by usual synchronization?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any synchronization constructs (was that a requirement? I think it should be to make this more interesting). You can do it simply like this:

```
public class ThreadOrder {

    public static class WaitingForMyTurn extends Thread {

        private static volatile Integer currentNumber = 1;
        private Integer myNumber;

        public WaitingForMyTurn(Integer number) {
            this.myNumber = number;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (currentNumber < myNumber) {
            }
            System.out.println(myNumber);
            currentNumber = myNumber + 1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new WaitingForMyTurn(i).start();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: made currentNumber volatile

Comment: currentNumber needs to be volatile or threads might never see any updates.